# Flicker of black when displaying hidden image for first time on HTML5 web app with jQuery Mobile (mobile Safari on iPhone 4)

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, html, jquery-mobile

We're using jQuery Mobile to create a web app for iOS devices.

In testing on the iPhone, we noticed hidden images that appear via jQuery (e.g., show, fadeIn) for the first time will appear black momentarily before the image loads into the element.

Per the advice of other SO posts, we load the images as background images to an element, which allows us to account for Retina vs. non-Retina displays.

We don't believe this is related to the flicker problem described in other SO posts, as we already implemented the "ui-page" solution.

We suspect this is due to jQuery only loading visible background images first. We can hack this, of course, by showing elements off screen, but we're wondering if a more elegant workaround exists.

Comment: Thanks for the edit ... up too late last night, typo! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can preload CSS background images by creating Image objects and setting their src. This will make the request in the background and cache it (at least in desktop browsers, I don't have an iPhone to test). CSS background images alone are not loaded until they are shown, afaik.

```
var imageSources = ["/images/1.png", "/images/2.png", "/images/3.png"];

jQuery.each( imageSources,
    function( index, src ) {
    var img = new Image();

        img.onload = function(){
            if( this.isLoaded ) {
            return;
            }
        this.isLoaded = true;
        jQuery ( document ).trigger( "imageloaded", [this.src] );
        };

    img.src = src;

        if( ( img.complete || img.readyState === 4 ) && !img.isLoaded ) {
        img.onload();
        }

    }
);


jQuery( document ).bind( "imageloaded",
    function( e, src ) {
    //div with background-image url == src can be displayed
    }
);
```

edit: ran some tests and firefox didn't load background image until it was shown while google chrome loaded it anyway:

```
[00:13:44.087] document.getElementById("e").style.display = "block";
[00:13:44.090] "block"
[00:13:44.102] GET http://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b012877702708970c-pi
```

css

```
#e{
background-image: url('http://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b012877702708970c-pi');
display: none;
}
```

Comment: Ah, so it's not a jQuery Mobile thing?

Comment: If by a jQuery mobile thing you mean CSS background images not preloading until rendered on screen, yes it is same in desktop browsers AFAIK.

Comment: Since you're not positive, we'll wait a bit before awarding the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Not a big deal, I have used this same code in 3 of my SO answers in the last 2 days :)